# Do Salafis disapprove of Nowruz?

Tags: culture, salafi

Do Salafis disapprove of [Nowruz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowruz)?

I know that Salafis disapprove of some festivals. For example, Saudi Arabia's religious police ban [Valentine's Day](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsbeat/article/31382332/valentines-day-countries-that-dont-love-february-romance). Is Nowruz a festival they disapprove of?

Comment: Well AFAIK all Sunni people would disapprove it as Sunni sourcesexplain that one of the 2 days which were celebrated in Jahilya and replaced by the 2 'ids (which are quoted in almost all hadith collections) was Nowruz. And Shia'a sources are Quoting a statement of Imam Ja'afar as-Sadiq allowing it, but as far as i understood the source is apparently doubtful!

Comment: Nowruz is a cultural issue and not related to religion.   Quran makes no mention of two Eids either, so Eid is arab culture.

Comment: It is quite true that Nowruz is a cultural issue and not related to religion (as @Sayyid correctly pointed)...

Comment: @Sayyid How Eid is considered as cultural as it was ordered by Our Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him to be celbrated by all muslims,so he has said, after seeing that the people of Madina had two holidays which they celebrated from before Islam, which is reported by Anas ibn Maalik that the Prophet sallallaahu 'alayhi wa sallam said,
"Allah has given you better than those feasts: the ‘Eid-ul-Adh-haa (Feast of Sacrificing), and ‘Eid-ul-Fitr (feast of Breaking the fast)." (Nasai,dawud)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Do Salafis disapprove of Nowruz?

Probably they do. Salafi sources seems to indicate that they consider celebrating Nowruz as haram. IslamQA (the most reputable and popular Salafi website) writes in a Fatawa :

> The Muslims do not have any festivals which they celebrate except Eid
> al-Fitr and Eid al-Adha. Anything other than that is an innovated
> festival and **it is not permissible to celebrate it**.
>
> [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/101404)